# Process Subscription on Roster has got messed after new attribute has been added Ejabbered

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, instant-messaging

**I have a problem in the subscription process after adding a new attribute to the mod_roster_odbc.erl**

This obviously required  me to alter the table rosterusers adding a new column for the record as well as the queries get_roster (s) in the odbc_queries for this module. And then in the module mod_roster_odbc, I had to extend methods like process_iq (get and set(s)) methods and others like, record_to_string, raw_to_record, process_item_attrs, and also get_subscription_lists, and pending queries for the new attribute to be initialised when setting each element of the roster

I have tested my change to the point of setting each element of my roster and save it correctly to DB, the same goes for getting to roster and the new attribute/record is added just like expected.

Now, my problem is that I broke the subscription part in the client side. **The client logic subscribes to each element of the roster, before this changed I was able to subscribe automatically between two contacts being online. As far as I understand, user A sets user B in its roster and subscribes and then server sends presence to user B with this request so that user B subscribes back to user A and user finally get them subscribed as "Both"**. This is not happening after my change in the server.

Currently, user A is able to set user B to its roster but it does appear offline and I can see that subscription is "None" from rosterusers, basically one has the other on the roster but they do not manage to be subscribed or see each other online. Just until user A sends a message to user B subscription get processed and Both are subscribed to each other.

Now, I would like to avoid providing my code changes because I do ask for hints to know where I might have broken this logic in the server side. What would be the part of the presence that got broken with so small change....

Comment: did you try to set the subscription in database to `both`?

Comment: yes, but I would not like to alter the database myself, I would like that mod_roster_odbc subscribes to both automatically